# environment variables between workflow and job for github actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github

I'm creating workflow:
where environment variables are sets between workflow and jobs:
While accessing the workflow based env, I'm getting error:

```
Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.ACCOUNT_ID
```

all I want to access the job based env to each steps while referring to workflow based env.

The workflow

```
env:
 AWS_REGION: ${{ vars.AWS_REGION }}
 ACCOUNT_ID: ${{ secrets.TRAINING_ACCOUNT_ID }}

jobs:
 dev:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ env.ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{env.AWS_REGION}}.amazonaws.com
  steps:
   - name: build
     run: |
       aws --region ${{env.AWS_REGION}} ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${{env.ECR_REGISTRY}}
```

Comment: have you tried referencing with `${{ ACCOUNT_ID }}` instead of `${{ env.ACCOUNT_ID}}`

Comment: No, I tried this, but I think I found the solution. This is not written anywhere, if anyone can confirm this is the solution, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I found this as answer after a quite trial, if someone has the official answer, please post it.
But to work in my case, this is the hack:

```
env:
 AWS_REGION: ${{ vars.AWS_REGION }}
 ACCOUNT_ID: ${{ secrets.TRAINING_ACCOUNT_ID }}

jobs:
 dev:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      ECR_REGISTRY: $ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com
  steps:
   - name: build
     run: |
       aws --region ${{env.AWS_REGION}} ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${{env.ECR_REGISTRY}}
```